# Extjs 3.0 Grid Filter, load options from store

Tags: gridview, extjs, filter, header

I am trying to implement Ext.ux.grid.filter.ListFilter using a data store (rather than a hardcoded list) as covered here in the ExtJS 4 API - [Ext.ux.grid.filter.ListFilterView source...](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.filter.ListFilter). I see a filter option on this column header but now I would like to know how to load options from store?? I tried it with code below but it doesn't work.
If options are hardcoded the filter works OK.

here is some code:

```
var tradeStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        fields: ['tradegroup_id','tradegroup_name'],
        data: [
            { tradegroup_id: 1, tradegroup_name: '10 T-shirts' },
            { tradegroup_id: 2, tradegroup_name: '15 polo' },
            { tradegroup_id: 3, tradegroup_name: '60 Pants' },
            { tradegroup_id: 4, tradegroup_name: '62 Denim' } 
        ],
        autoLoad: {
            // this callback function is actually Ext js 4, how to convert it to Ext js 3?
            callback: function() {
                grid.getView().getHeaderCt().child('#Trademark').initialConfig.filter.options = tradeStore.collect('tradegroup_name'); 
            }
        }
    });

    _filtersPlugin = new Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters({
        encode: encode, // json encode the filter query
        local: local,   // defaults to false (remote filtering)
        filters: [
            {
                type: 'list',
                dataIndex: 'Trademark',
                options: [] 
                // options: ['10 T-shirts', '60 Pants']   // this is harcoded, I don't want this
                store: tradeStore

            },
        ]
```

Comment: I solved it. I just load data from store, I didn't know that could be so easy.
Here is the code:  

    var trademarkFilterOptions = [];
        WebApp.Order.Data.tradegroupStore.each(function(record) {
            trademarkFilterOptions.push(record.data.tradegroup_name);
        });

Comment: I would post as an answer, but I have to wait 8 hours.